# How to write a script to delete multiple files in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scripting

I am new to scripting and trying to write a python script to remove a few files.. Here is the path Multiple scripts/script*

```
Main directory: Multiple scripts
sub directories: script1
                 script2
                 script3
```

In each script in subdirectories, I have file consists of mem. Since I don't know what they start with or their extension now I would like to write a script to search all the subdirectories and delete files that consists of mem.

I tried using the following code but did not work for me

```
import os
if Multiple scripts/scripts*
    os.remove(*/mem*)
else:
    print ("file does not exists")
```

And also please help me with how to write a script to delete files with multiple names (*/mem*, */name*) at a time. Any help would be appreciated... Thank you

Comment: What is “if Multiple” (supposed to be)?

Comment: @Davis Herring What I mean is how can we write a script to delete two or more files with different names at a time

Comment: Unless you are *specifically* asking about how to solve a cross-version compatibility problem (in which case your question should obviously describe that problem) you should not mix the [tag:python-2.7] and [tag:python-3.x] tags.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, I think you'll want the [glob module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html). Something like

```
import os
import glob
for fname in glob.iglob("./*/mem*"):
    print("Removing "+fname)
    os.remove(fname)
```

Before you run that loop, though, I'd say run it first without the last line, to see what it would do, and make sure that that's what you want.

Comment: how about the path? I mean where it should go and delete

Comment: @user7090 If you're running the script from some other directory, you'd replace the "." with the path to the base directory. The "." here simply indicates a "relative path", telling it to search the current directory.

Comment: It didnot print anything

Comment: @user7090 It's not clear what the problem is. How about you read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#Absolute_and_relative_paths) and see if it clears anything up.